# Need to add <!-- before a tag in an xml file using shell

Tags: shell

My input file is below

INPUT FILE

```
<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I have code which looks like

```
LineNum=`grep -n "Deep" deep.xml | cut -d: -f 1 | awk -F '[\t]' '{$NF = $NF -1;}1'`
sed -i "/$LineNum/s/^/<!--/" deep.xml
```

What i need is:- i want to go to the line number which i am getting with LineNum variable and i want to add <!-- before an xml tag. So that my sample output looks like below

```
<!--<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I am not able to do that. Can anyone tell what mistake i am doing in the code?

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Please, [avoid cross posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -- this question appears to also be on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66565461/10488700

Answer (score 0):

The first set of `/` in your sed line means "search for a line *containing* `$LineNum`"

What you really want is

```
sed -i "${LineNum}s/^/<!--/" deep.xml
```

Now that says "On line ${LineNum} do this `s` command..."

A very simple example where I replace the "e" on line 2 with the word "HELLO"

```
$ cat x
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef

$ sed '2s/e/HELLO/' x
abcdef
abcdHELLOf
abcdef
```

Comment: When i am using this "sed -i "${LineNum}s/^/<!--/" deep.xml" command i am getting sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: ` '